# How to write down product operators acting on non-adjacent subsystems?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology-and-notation, projection-operator

Given the following fusion gate (type-2) which is projecting 2 qubits to an even state

$$F_{ZZ}=(\langle00|+\langle|11|)$$

I would like to find the operator for the bigger space. For example, if I have 4 qubits, and I fusion 2 and 3:

$$U = I^1 \otimes F_{ZZ}^{2,3} \otimes I^4$$

Clearly, U is collapsing the state from 4 qubits to 2 qubits.

**Question:** How can I build $U$ if the 2 fusion qubits are not neighbors? For example, qubits $1$ and $3$ or qubits $2$ and $4$ or $1$ and $4$. I want a very practical approach, where I can use $U$ to multiply any state $Ux$ without changing the internal order of $x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can exploit the [distributive law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property). For example, the operator projecting onto the even subspace of qubits $1$ and $3$ can be written as

$$
\langle 0|_1\otimes I_2\otimes\langle 0|_3\otimes I_4+
\langle 1|_1\otimes I_2\otimes\langle 1|_3\otimes I_4\tag1
$$

or more condensed

$$
\sum_{k\in\{0,1\}}\langle k|_1\otimes I_2\otimes\langle k|_3\otimes I_4.\tag2
$$

You can reduce clutter by making identity operators implicit

$$
\langle 00|_{1,3}+\langle 11|_{1,3}.\tag3
$$

Similarly for other pairs of qubits.

---

The slight awkwardness of the notation is a symptom of the limitations of the traditional one-dimensional notation for linear algebra. See tensor networks and ZX-calculus for alternatives that use two-dimensional diagrams.